# Chrome API to get the start time of a Tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I was looking for an API to get the start time or time the tab was opened. Well, Chrome API documentation has not mentioned anything here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.

Should I inject a time checker inside tabs manually when they were opened(started)?

Comment: You can use [`onCreated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated) and [`onRemoved`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onRemoved) in the background script and after they fire you can run a simple function that gets the current time and saves it.

Comment: @PredatorIWD How to get time when user manually opens(creates) a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create your own map of tabs created time and remove that when a tab is removed by this code. Run below code in background and keep your background persisted (Can be done in `manifest` file)

```
var openTabs = {};
chrome.tabs.onCreated(function(tab) {
    openTab[tab.id] = new Date();
});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved(function(tab) {
    if (openTabs[tab.id]) {
        delete openTabs[tab.id]
    }
});
```

Now you can simply ask for this time in content script by passing message.